# How to use Amazon ElastiCache with DynamoDB in Python to improve read/write performance

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elasticache

I have a DynamoDB instance created in AWS and I have also created a cache cluster in AWS Elasticache. I want to use Elasticache to improve read/write performance. I am not sure how this is done with Python.

Can you please provide pointers/guidance on how to attach the Elasticache to my DynamoDB instance?  I was able to connect to the Elasticache and fetch the clusters, but need help on how to proceed.

Reference code:

```
conn = boto.elasticache.connect_to_region('us-west-2',
    aws_access_key_id='<KEY_ID>',
    aws_secret_access_key='<KEY_ACCESS>')
print conn.describe_cache_clusters(cache_cluster_id='<ID>')
```

Comment: Why do you need to improve DynamoDB read performance? DynamoDB queries generally have single-digit millisecond latency. Adding a cache will add complexity with likely very little impact on performance. If your DynamoDB reads are that slow, you're probably using it wrong and/or have not designed your data model well.

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you mean by "attach the Elasticache to my DynamoDB instance"?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article that describes a similar situation involving Elasticache and DynamoDB. The code is in node, but will help you understand how to do this.

[Caching Strategy with DynamoDB Streams, AWS Lambda and ElastiCache](https://medium.com/@FherPereiro/caching-strategy-with-dynamodb-streams-aws-lambda-and-elasticache-2b309333cff9)